# How many ways are there of creating an $8$ character password with a digit, a lowercase letter, and $2$ capital letters?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

> A valid password for the bank's website consists of 8 characters
> (digits and letters in English) and must contain at least one digit,
> at least one small English letter, and at least two capital letters.
> How many legal passwords are there?

I considered four sets:

- $|A|$ = number of ways for no digits appearing in the password = $52^8$,
- $|B|$ = number of ways of no small letter in the password = $36^8$,
- $|C|$ = number of ways of no capital letter in the password = $36^8$,
- $|D|$ = number of ways of only 1 capital letter in the password = $26*36^7$, and
- $|U|$ = number of ways of forming the bank's password without restriction  = $62^8$.

Using the formula for inclusion and exclusion for 4 sets $|U| - [ |A| \cup |B| \cup |C|\cup |D|]$

such that

$$
\begin{align}
&|A\cup B\cup C\cup D|\\[3pt]
&=|A|+|B|+|C|+|D|\Big\}\text{ all singletons}\\
&-(|A\cap B|+|A\cap C|+|A\cap D|+|B\cap C|+|B\cap D|+|C\cap D|)\Big\}\text{ all pairs}\\
&+(|A\cap B\cap C|+|A\cap B\cap D|+|A\cap C\cap D|+|B\cap C\cap D|)\Big\}\text{ all triples}\\
&-|A\cap B\cap C\cap D|\Big\}\text{ all quadruples.}\\
\end{align}
$$

**Now what I'm stuck at is** when it comes to triples and quadruples.

$|A\cap B\cap C\cap D|$, to find the number of ways of union of this is kinda contradicting because we have to find a password with no digits, no small letters, no big letters, but only 1 small letter..

or when

$|A\cap C\cap D|$ is also contradicting because how we can find number of ways of password with no big letters and also 1 big letter..

Comment: It's not contradicting; it's just zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no contradiction, just note that $C\cap D=\emptyset$ and therefore all intersection sets including $C\cap D$ have zero cardinality. Moreover, by a similar reason, also $A\cap B\cap C=\emptyset$ and $A\cap B\cap D=\emptyset$. Thus it remains to compute
$$\begin{align}
&|U|-(|A|+|B|+|C|+|D|)+(|A\cap B|+|A\cap C|+|A\cap D|+|B\cap C|+|B\cap D|)
\end{align}
$$
P.S. One more thing, your number for $|D|$ should be multiplied by $8$, i.e. the possible positions of the capital letter.

Comment: so $|A\cap B\cap C\cap D|$ is also an empty set?

Comment: Yes, it is empty.

Comment: $|B\cap C\cap D$ also is an empty set? shouldn't be remaining  # of ways for forming a password from digits only so its $10^8$?

Comment: Yes, it is empty. It is a subset of $C\cap D$.

Comment: @LightLamps Have you a numeric answer?

Answer (score 2):

First, your evaluation of $|D|$ is incorrect. This is the number of ways to choose a capital letter for the first character, and then choose the remaining seven characters with no capitals. But in fact the single capital letter could be in any of $8$ positions, so actually $|D|=8\times 26\times 36^7$.

Secondly, the multiple events. Note that $C$ and $D$ cannot both occur, and no three events can occur (since if they include $A,B$ and one of $C,D$ then you have at most one character). So you only need to subtract the pairs of events (not including $|C\cup D|$), since the other terms are all $0$.

$|A\cap B|=26^8$, since this means all characters are capitals, and the other double events can be calculated similarly (ones involving $D$ are a bit more complicated, but no more so than the calculation for $D$ itself).

Comment: $|B\cap C\cap D$ also is an empty set? shouldn't be remaining  # of ways for forming a password from digits only so its $10^8$?

Comment: @LightLamps yes, it's empty. The point is that C requires no capitals and D requires exactly one capital - there is no way to satisfy both.

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify the expression a bit by combining set of no capital letter and set of one capital letter as there is no intersection between them.

If $A$ is the set of passwords where we have at most one capital letter, $B$ is the set of passwords with no small letters and $C$ with no digits,

$|A| = 36^8 + 8 \times 26 \times 36^7$

$|B|= 36^8$

$|C| = 52^8$

$|A \cap B| = 10^8 + 8 \times 26 \times 10^7$

$|B \cap C| = 26^8$

$|A \cap C| = 26^8 + 8 \times 26 \times 26^7$

$|A \cap B \cap C| = 0$

$|A \cup B \cup C| = |A| + |B| + |C| - |A \cap B| - |B \cap C| - |A \cap C| + |A \cap B \cap C|$

And the answer will be $ \, \, 62^8 - |A \cup B \cup C|$